# Contact Form not sending

Tags: plugin-contactform

I'm using the [Pixel & Tonic Contact Form](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm) plugin.
I have created a template and I'm using the example code from the README file.

No email is being sent. Upon submit it redirects to the form page.  I have successfully sent myself an email test using Php Mail.

Do I need a template at:
`<input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm/sendMessage">`

This is my code:

```
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
        {% if errors %}
            <ul class="errors">
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endmacro %}

    {% from _self import errorList %}

    <form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        {{ getCsrfInput() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm/sendMessage">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/thank-you-for-contacting-us">

        <h3><label for="fromName" style="display:block">Your Name</label></h3>
        <input id="fromName" type="text" name="fromName" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromName }}{% endif %}">
        {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromName')) }}

        <h3><label for="fromEmail" style="display:block">Your Email</label></h3>
        <input id="fromEmail" type="text" name="fromEmail" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromEmail }}{% endif %}">
        {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromEmail')) }}

        <h3><label for="subject" style="display:block">Subject</label></h3>
        <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.subject }}{% endif %}">
        {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('subject')) }}

        <h3><label for="message" style="display:block">Message</label></h3>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="message" name="message">{% if message is defined %}{{ message.message }}{% endif %}</textarea>
        {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('message')) }}

        <input id="kneesbees" class="kneesbees" name="kneesbees" type="text">

<input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
```

Comment: You don't need a template at `contactForm/sendMessage` - that is the plugin action. So after submitting you don't get sent to "thank-you-for-contacting-us" ?

Comment: Thank you for responding. 
After submitting, the page reloads and no email is being sent.

Comment: It seems like the plugin is hitting a snag somewhere. Is this site in `devMode`? If so, you should see any problems and errors showing up in the logs.

Comment: The site is in devMode. Not really sure what to look for. I don't see anything in the log that is standing out.

Another oddity. If I fill out my honeypot field, it sends me to the thank you page but still does not send the email.

Could there be a server setting that is cause my issue?

Comment: I have moved over the the Mandrill plugin and have it working there.  I would love to see someone post a solution if they find it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what was happening. There was a conflict with a previously installed plugin, Sprout Invisible Captcha.

Comment: Might be worth contacting Barrel Strength Design to let them know about the conflict... that sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: I've just hit this same issue on a live site. Disabling Sprout Invisible Captcha fixed it. On version 2.6.2949 of Craft and 0.8.3 of Sprout Invisible Captcha.

Answer (score 0):

`phpmail` is notoriously unreliable at delivering emails.  It might work fine for you locally when sending a test email to yourself, but getting an email reliably delivered on the "real" internet is much more difficult.

Most likely you were just running into that unreliability and swapping to a transactional email provider like Mandrill solved the issue.

Comment: I think this is a problem with the Contact From plugin. I have tried it on three different servers using a variety of email protocols, and I still get the same result.

 The Mandrill plugin seems to work fine, but it is limited in functionality.

Comment: I also noticed that error messages are not working on this plugin either.  Could I be missing something simple?